# What is a cost of search for records in a table with an equality predicate on a non key attribute A and a static hash organization?

Tags: performance, hashing, query-performance

> To speed up the search for records in a table with an equality predicate on a non key attribute A and selectivity factor f<sub>s</sub>, is preferable:
>
> 1. A sequential organization on a key attribute ?
> 2. A static hash organisation on a key attribute ?
> 3. An inverted index on A

I have to justify the answer and give an estimate of query execution cost in all three cases.

To my mind it was

1. log<sub>2</sub>⌈N<sub>pag</sub>(R)⌉
   according to this :

[image: cost]

2. ? No info
3. it depends if it is a clustered or an unclustered index.

#### Professor answer :

1. **N<sub>pag</sub>(R)** *"because indexing is on the key"* and *"according to the screenshot"* (which is provided above, but for me he is wrong on the cell as far as it isn't a memory operation but a equality search)
2. **N<sub>pag</sub>(R**)
3. Yeah, it depends ...

I don't understand why is he saying the first and where does he take the second. My teacher uses [this book he co-writted](http://pages.di.unipi.it/ghelli/bd2/DBMS-Internals.pdf).